# Java Loop with sleep

Tags: java, infinite-loop, thread-sleep

To fulfill the needs of my company I need to implement a loop which

1. reads records which have a field equal to a flag,
2. either sleeps (if the result is empty) or performs tasks outlined by the data in the records
3. update statuses
4. and repeats 1.

The user of the loop should be able to to switch of the loop by setting a flag from outside the loop.

I have tried implementing it using a `while` loop with `sleep` but I would like to know if there are better alternatives.

Comment: Maybe you have a look at `.wait()`.

Comment: I would suggest looking into [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Comment: @RexWagenius I am looking at it now. Maybe it helps to give me an example with my need in mind.

Comment: Please define sleep. What should wake it up ?

Comment: You should go to a blog to search the same.

Comment: @SaviNuclear Looks like you are another pessimist on Stackoverflow who thinks those who ask questions have not done research before they post their questions. Q&A users sometimes give insightful answers to your problems and these answers may be useful to users who may have similar problems in the future.

Comment: I wonder why was the question down voted ?

Comment: @c0der That's what I am wondering too. I thought I had a valid question.

Comment: If you did then some thing to understand from your point of view

Comment: @Blobonat Using threads api can be touchy and more complicated than using `Timer`. Anyway I think `Timer`'s implementation is based uses `wait`.

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly would use a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and a [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) which seem to fulfill your requirements and are already included in the JDK.

Otherwise you can also have a look at [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) which is more complete.

Here’s an example of using a timer to perform a task once per second inspired by [this page](http://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/05Aug/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html):

```
public class Reminder {
Timer timer;

public startReminder() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(),
                   0,        //initial delay
                   1*1000);  //subsequent rate
}

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Time's up!");
        //use timer.cancel() to stop the reminder
    }
}
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`javafx.animation.PauseTransition` is also an option:

```
    PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(
            Duration.seconds(2)
    );
    pause.setOnFinished(event -> System.out.println("Woke up...."));
    System.out.println("Going to sleep....");
    pause.play();
```

Comment: I don't know much about Javafx but `PauseTransion` is intended to be  executed one time. `TimeLine` seems to better fit the requirements. Anyway I don't like the idea of using presentation level elements in what looks like backend code.

Comment: I agree. It is not suitable for every purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A **cron job** (Unix style name), task scheduler. A search will yield some libraries like quartz. They are timer based.